# Get model identity from model instance

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Is it possible to get a model's name/identity from an instance of that model? I would like to be able to pass a model to a service and have that service perform an action on that model based on what type of model it is.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Waterline's shortcomings forced me to transition to sequelize not too long after asking this question.  


I don't have any way of testing if your solution would actually work because I no longer use waterline (or sails) for anything.

Comment: Would you share your experience of the transition? Where did you find most useful information to get started?

Answer (score 3):

In lifecycle callbacks for example you can access the model identity with :

```
this.adapter.identity;
```